# AJax форма для интернет магазина

Tags: ajax, yii2, action

Здравствуйте. У меня есть форма для интернет магазина отправление продукта  в корзину.

```
<form id="myform">

<input type="button" value="+"  onclick="addProduct(<?=$result->id?>)">
<input type="text" size="4"  value=0 name="javob" id='<?=$result->id ?>'>
<input type="button" value="-"  onclick="removeProduct(<?=$result->id?>)">
```

здесь выбирается количество продуктов и отправляется в корзину.А мне надо      когда user выбирает это продукта и отправляет в корзину записалась в БД. Я нашел некий пример но у меня не получилось. Помогите пожалуйста новичку. 
Вот мой пример.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/main/Create',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            count: $_POST["javob"].val();
            product_id: $result->product_id.val();
            user_id: Yii::app->user->id.val(); 
            price: $result->price.val();
            status: 0;
            date: Data();
        },                        
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: покажите ещё код `actionCreate()` контроллера `main`

Comment: Ну вот задумалась в actione